# How would you tidy up this Mysql query logic

Tags: php, mysql

I'm showing daily basis data. Say One Human(HumanID) daily eat 2 times morning , evening. So i input data like this.

Table: report

```
-----------------------------------------------
ID  | HumanID |  date      | schedule | amount|  
-----------------------------------------------
1  |  101     | 2016-01-01 | morning  |  10   |
2  |  101     | 2016-01-01 | evening  |  8    |
3  |  102     | 2016-01-01 | morning  |  11   |
4  |  102     | 2016-01-01 | evening  |  9    |
5  |  103     | 2016-01-01 | morning  |  8    |
6  |  103     | 2016-01-01 | evening  |  7    |
```

I do Mysql Query:

```
select HumanID, date, 
max(case when schedule = 'morning' then amount end) as morning, 
max(case when schedule = 'evening' then amount end) as evening
from report 
group by HumanID, date;
```

After Query , Result Came up like this

```
---------------------------------------
HumanID |  date      | morning | evening |  
---------------------------------------
101     | 2016-01-01 |   10    |   8     |
102     | 2016-01-01 |   11    |   9     |
103     | 2016-01-01 |   8     |   7     |
```

What i want in php logic , result will be look like this

```
---------------------------------------
HumanID |  date      | morning | evening |  
---------------------------------------
101     | 2016-01-01 |   10    |   8     |
102     | 2016-01-01 |   11    |   9     |
103     | 2016-01-01 |   8     |   7     |
------------------------------------------
Total:               |   29    |   24    |
```

Comment: Did you try to use `SUM()` in your query?

Comment: What php have you tried so far?

Comment: Sum instead of max. And ROLLUP. But actually I'd do the whole formatting part of this in php

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding this result with `UNION` :

```
SELECT CAST(t.humanID as char) as humanID,t.date,
       MAX(.... )
..... -- Rest of your query
UNION ALL
SELECT 'total:' as humanID , null ,
         SUM(case when schedule = 'morning' then amount end) , 
         SUM(case when schedule = 'evening' then amount end) 
FROM report
ORDER BY humanID
```

Answer (score 0):

E.g.:

```
select HumanID, date, 
Sum(case when schedule = 'morning' then amount end) as morning, 
Sum(case when schedule = 'evening' then amount end) as evening
from report 
group by HumanID, date
With ROLLUP
```